# string to replace specific characters

Tags: c#, replace

For example =>
iddaa///news/haber05112013.jpg

Result=>
iddaa/news/haber05112013.jpg

I want to replace this spesific characters ("/");
But sometimes double characters ('///') , sometimes ('//')
can ı replace this?
Thank you

Comment: it depends what you mean for sometimes. explain it better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't know how many repetitions there are, use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var res = Regex.Replace(orig, "/+", "/");
```

`"/+"` is a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that matches one or more forward slash.

Comment: Thank you.This is ok for me

Answer (score 0):

This code will handle any length of `/` sequence:

```
string a = //some string
while(a.Contains(@"//"))
{
    a = a.Replace(@"//",@"/");
}
```

@dasblinkenlight answer is better. Regex is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way is :

```
string str = "iddaa///news/haber05112013.jpg";
str = str.Replace("///", "/").Replace("//","/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regular expression. Try this:

```
var strTargetString = @"iddaa///news/haber05112013.jpg";
var strRegex = @"/+";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
var strReplace = @"/";
var result =  myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```